# Receiving signal during malloc

Tags: c, linux, malloc

I want program to write stack content into the file after receiving a signal during `malloc()`. To do this I tried to use `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols_fd()` functions, but later discovered that they were not async-signal-safe. I wrote the following code just to test and it appeared that the program hung in most runs.

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

static void signal_handler_child(int sig)
{
    char error_msg_buffer[4096];

    int fd = open("./backtrace_log.txt", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0777);

    strcpy(error_msg_buffer, "entered signal_handler_child()");
    write(fd, error_msg_buffer, strlen(error_msg_buffer));

    void* buffer[1024];
    const int size = backtrace(buffer, 1024);

    if(size <= 0)
    {
        strcpy(error_msg_buffer, "unable to dump call stack trace: backtrace() returned bad size");
        write(fd, error_msg_buffer, strlen(error_msg_buffer));
        return ;
    }

    backtrace_symbols_fd(buffer, size, fd);

    close(fd);

    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler_child);
        while(true)
        {
            void *pointer = malloc(1000000);
            free(pointer);
        }
    }
    else if(pid == -1)
    {
        printf("fork() error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(3);

        if(kill(pid, SIGSEGV) == -1)
            printf("kill() error\n");

        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

So how can I safely write stack content into a file in such kind of situation? Can `backtrace()` use `malloc()` underneath in general?

Also the man page says

> backtrace_symbols_fd() does not call malloc(3), and so can be employed
>   in situations where the latter function might fail.

But what is the point of function `backtrace_symbols_fd()`, if `backtrace()` actually is affected by `malloc()`?

I'm new to linux api, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: How far into your signal handler do you get?  Does your output file get created?  Do you see any of the output in the file?  I don't see anything in [the `backtrace()` source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/debug/backtrace.c.html) that should cause a deadlock.  You can try adding something to write the pointers returned from `backtrace()` to the file. You can run `pstack PID` from a command line against your deadlocked process to see where it's hung.  Also, you probably want to add a `\n` character to the end of each string you write to the file.

Comment: `malloc` isn’t any more likely to suffer a signal or interfere with a handler than anything else.  Why test it specifically?

Comment: @Peach: Many modern systems [restrict `ptrace` to parent processes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) by default.  If you can, use `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary reason why `backtrace` calls `malloc` is that it needs to load `libgcc_s` using `dlopen`.  You can get some additional reliability by calling `backtrace` first to initialize itself.  Subsequent calls to `backtrace` should not trigger calls to `malloc`, as the following example shows.

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *
malloc (size_t size)
{
  const char *message = "malloc called\n";
  write (STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen (message));
  void *next = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
  return ((__typeof__ (malloc) *) next) (size);
}

int
main (void)
{
  /* This calls malloc.  */
  puts ("First call to backtrace.");
  void *buffer[10];
  backtrace (buffer, 10);
  /* This does not.  */
  puts ("Second call to backtrace.");
  backtrace (buffer, 10);
}
```

The libgcc unwinder is still not async-signal-safe for other reasons, but glibc assumes it is (for things like thread cancellation), and it generally works as if it were async-signal-safe.

Comment: I am just pondering the effects of calling backtrace "first".
In "normal" cases (i.e. a program never gets SIGSEGV) when a SIGSEGV handler is used that way(as show in OP), the libgcc_s would only be loaded when a SIGSEGV happens. But in this way, while making it more reliable, it appears the loading of libgcc_s is done even when SIGSEGV doesn't happen. Are there any additional overhead to loading libgcc_s when that's not needed at all? Or it's some negilible overhead that happens just once?

Comment: You just need to call `backtrace` once, so the overhead is quite minimal. Loading `libgcc_s` only needs a bit of additional memory, its mere presence in the process image will not slow down the program.

Answer (score 1):

`backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` are asyc-signal-unsafe and `backtrace_symbols_fd()` is async-signal-safe. You can read the details in [GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html).

> But what is the point of function backtrace_symbols_fd(), if backtrace() actually is affected by malloc?

backtrace mechanism is not *only* for getting backtrace when a signal occurs - even in normal cases it might be used. Besides the man page doesn't say `backtrace()` is affected by `malloc()`. It says that about `backtrace_symbols()` functions. Quoting the full paragraph from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html):

> backtrace_symbols_fd() takes the same buffer and size arguments as backtrace_symbols(), but instead of returning an array  of  strings  to  the  caller,  it writes the strings, one per line, to the file descriptor fd.  backtrace_symbols_fd() does not call malloc(3), and so can be employed in situations where the latter function might fail.

But then GNU documentation marked `backtrace` as asyn-csignal-unsafe anyway. So it's unsafe to call it from signal handler even if it doesn't affected by malloc(). But when you are in a SIGSEGV handler, chances are that you are already in a dire situation (SIGSEGV that you are handling was likely caused by some undefined behaviour already). In summary there's no safe way to use `backtrace()` from a signal handler. Calling `backtrace()` is simply unsafe (no strong guarantees), but likely works well in most cases.